# Построить список из масива

Tags: javascript

Не могу совладать с задачей, прошу Вашей помощи!

**Задача:** Напишите функцию arrayToList, которая строит такую структуру, получая в качестве аргумента [1, 2, 3]

```
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

**Решение:** сейчас я вижу такое решение, но описать его кодом не могу (если, конечно, придуманное мною решение в принципе решает поставленную задачу.

**Что я сделал**

```js
function arrayToList(array) {

  var list = {
    value: null,
    rest: {}
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    list.value = array[i];
    list.rest = array.splice(0,1);
  }
  return list;
}

console.log(arrayToList([1,2,3]));
```

На мой взгляд:

1. Нужно пройтись по каждому элементу массива, переданного в качестве аргумента.
2. Первый элемент переданого массива присвоить методу `list.value`
3. После этого, нужно "каким-то образом" получить "исходный массив - первый элемент, ранее присвоенный `list.value`". Я пробовал splice, shift - но не получается.
4. Почему-то мне кажется, что методу `list.rest` нужно как-то рекурсивно передавать эту же функцию `arrayToList`, только, соответственно, с удаленным первым элементом, чтобы он рекурсивно вызывалась до тех пор, пока исходный переданный массив не будет пустым.
5. Но, ничего не выходит.

Буду очень признателен за помощь. Мне не совсем нужен код, как формальность в описании действий (я так лучше понимаю). Спасибо!

p.s. конкретно в моем примере должно получиться так:

```
console.log(arrayToList([1, 2, 3]);
{ 
    value: 1,
    rest: {
        value 2,
        rest: {
            value: 3,
            rest: undefined
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу такой вариант (если я верно истолковал задание, пункт 3 не мовсем прозрачен для меня) :

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  // проверяем что мы чтото получили в аргумент 
  // и ето чтото масив, с количеством елементов > 0
  if (!array || !Array.isArray(array) || !array.length)
    // тут нужно еще подумать, что именно возвращать (в зависимости что вам нужно)
    return undefined

  var list = {
    // сразу нулевой елемент присваиваем в value
    value: array[0],
    rest: {}
  }

  // проверяем если длина масива > 0 то удаляем первый елемент
  // а в поле rest присваиваем результат выполения етой же функции над новым масивом (рекурсия)
  if (array.length) {
    array.shift()
    list.rest = arrayToList(array)
  }

  return list
}

const listToArray = list => {
  const res = []
  res.push(list.value)

  if (list.rest)
    return [...res, ...listToArray(list.rest)]

  return res
}

const res = arrayToList([1, 2, 3])
console.log(res)
console.log(listToArray(res))
```

Comment: проверка - хорошая вещь, я почему-то не подумал о ней. Но, может я не совсем корректно выразился. Смотрите: в объекте list есть метод value (простое значение, в моем случае - число) и "метод - объект" rest, который циклично повторяет структуру "объекта уровнем выше".

То есть должно получиться что-то такое: {value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: { value: 4, rest { ......, { value: N, rest: undefined}}}}}

Comment: @ТимурЖумашев понял вас, ето нужно было такой пример сразу в вопрос записать, щасс глянем, как ето сделать коректно)

Comment: ссылка на учебник, в котором описана задача https://karmazzin.gitbooks.io/eloquentjavascript_ru/content/chapters/chapter4.html#%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: @ТимурЖумашев посмотрите получилось ли то что надо ?

Comment: не могу обратиться к Вам через "@", не знаю почему. Да, получилось именно так, как нужно! Изучаю Ваши комментарии)

Comment: @ТимурЖумашев мне всеравно видны коменты, настряпал обратную функу, спрашивайте что не понятно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101902/discussion-between-rostyslav-kuzmovych-and--).

Answer (score 4):

Данную задачу можно решить с помощью свертки массива в объект. В данном случае сворачивать удобнее с конца, для этого нужно использовать метод [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight).

Свертку можно выразить следующей последовательностью действий:

1. создать объект
2. текущий элемент записать в поле `value`
3. то что пришло с предыдущего шага записать в поле `rest`

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  return array.reduceRight((acc, cur) => ({
    value: cur,
    rest: acc
  }), null)
}

console.log(arrayToList([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

---

Те же шаги можно сделать и с помощью рекурсии

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  if (array.length == 0) return null;
  var [value, ...rest] = array;
  return {
    value,
    rest: arrayToList(rest)
  };
}

console.log(arrayToList([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

Comment: спасибо! Просто на момент написания вопроса я ещё не был знаком с "функциями высшего порядка" (по крайней мере, так они называются в учебнике). То есть, фактически пару часов назад я не знал о том, как передавать массив и функцию для обработки этого массива)))

А конструкции типа => я пока игнорирую, я не дошел до них и не понимаю, как они работают)